# Passing param to route React native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, stack-navigator

I'm trying to pass a param to a new screen in order to display it. my object is in a fetched data of array that i display using map, the code looks like this:

```
 <Text > Show:</Text>
{
                        this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
                            //Show only two dates 
                            return (i < 2) ?
                                <View>
                                    <Text>{moment(item[0]).format("ddd DD/MM")}</Text>
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                        {
                                            item[1].map((day, i) => {
                                                //show only 3 times
                                                return (i < 3) ?
                                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('myScreen',//what should i wright here!>
                                                    <Text>{moment(day.date_start).format("h:mm a")}</Text> // i want to pass this displayed text {moment(day.date_start).format("h:mm a")}
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                                    :
                                                    <></>
                                            })
                                        }
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                : <></>

                        })
                    }
```

so as you can see i want to pass {moment(day.date_start).format("h:mm a")} to myScreen and display it, but i can't figure out how.
myScreen code is simple:

```
class Myscreen extends React.Component {


  render() {

    return (
<Text>  display it here!   </Text>
```

i would appreciate some help.thank you

Comment: Whats the navigation library that you are using ? and NavigationService or Navigation ?

Comment: i m using the latest version react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1"

Comment: @AymenAymen I think you have to upgrade your version to ^5.x.x. Example: "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.14"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first screen, you have to pass the text like this...

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('myScreen', { text: moment(day.date_start).format("h:mm a") })}>
  <Text>Press me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In your myScreen, you have to receive it like this...

```
class Myscreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.props.route.params.text;
    return (
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

Please make sure that you are using `@react-navigation/stack": "^5.x.x`

Comment: yes i do "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.3", and thank you your answer worked!